# What is the difference between MySQL grouped indexes and single indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing, phpmyadmin, database-performance, database-optimization

In PHP Admin when checking my indexes, I found some grouped indexes and some single indexes.
1) Are my indexes for e.g. post_status indexed twice?
2) If so, which one is best to delete? The grouped or single one?

See screenshot:
[image]

Comment: The `post_type` index is redundant, and can be dropped. The `post_status` index is *not* redundant, since there isn't any other index that has `post_status` as the leading column.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Multiple-column index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

> MySQL can use multiple-column indexes for queries that test all the columns in the index, or queries that test just the first column, the first two columns, the first three columns, and so on. If you specify the columns in the right order in the index definition, a single composite index can speed up several kinds of queries on the same table.

So your `type_status_date` index will be used if your filter criteria include all columns, one leftmost column, two leftmost column, and so on, such as

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE 
   post_type=a_constant_value1 AND
   post_status=a_constant_value2 AND
   post_date=a_constant_value3 AND
   post_author=a_constant_value4 AND
   id=a_constant_value5;  

SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE 
   post_type=a_constant_value1 AND
   post_status=a_constant_value2 AND
   post_date=a_constant_value3 AND
   post_author=a_constant_value4;

SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE 
   post_type=a_constant_value1 AND
   post_status=a_constant_value2 AND
   post_date=a_constant_value3;

SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE 
   post_type=a_constant_value1 AND
   post_status=a_constant_value2;

SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE 
   post_type=a_constant_value1;
```

So `post_type` index for `post_type` column is redundant index so it can be deleted. `id` column in `type_status_date` index also redundant because `id` column is primary key. You can delete 'id' column in `type_status_date` index.

If you never use all columns in any queries, remove any unused columns.

But following query will not be able to use `type_status_date` index because `post_status` is not leftmost column in `type_status_date` index. For this query `post_status` index will be used.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE 
   post_status=a_constant_value1;
```

Comment: I see! Maybe it's better to have them all as single indexes then?

Comment: It depends on how your actual query. If you are not sure, then use `EXPLAIN` to identify what index is selected for a particular query. This article discuss performance between multiple-column index vs multiple indexes https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/03/multiple-column-index-vs-multiple-indexes-with-mysql-56/

Comment: [More](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) on deciding on single- vs. multi-column indexing.

Comment: @mesqueeb:  no, that's not necessarily better.  Any query that could make effective use of the index on `(type)` could make effective use of an index on `(type,status,date)`. With that second index available, we can drop that first index, on the singleton `(type)` column, since it's redundant. For a query with predicates like: `type='a' and status='b' and date>='2016-03-01' and date <'2016-04-01'`, that composite index on `(type,status,date)` is better. That will be a more effective index than any singleton column indexes. Your choice of indexes really depends on the queries you're running.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Are my indexes for e.g. post_status indexed twice?**

The `post_status` index is not redundant. There isn't any other index that has `post_status` as the leading column.

But the `post_type` index is redundant.

The `post_type` column is (in your words) "indexed twice".

It's the leading column in two indexes: `post_type` and `type_status_date`.

**2) If so, which one is best to delete? The grouped or single one?**

If the `type_status_date` composite index is used by any query, then the index to drop would be the index on the single column `post_type`.